# Is there a difference between Pytorch 0.4.1 and 1.1.0

Tags: pytorch

When I finished my training task of semantic segmentation (pytorch 0.4.1 GPU CUDA9.0), and successed in inference of the model(pytorch 0.4.1), however when I switched my pytorch version to 1.1.0, I got slightly different result. What's the problem???

Comment: I didn't adjust any code before and after switching the version of pytroch

Comment: give us an example, please

Answer (score 0):

I found where the difference existed using just one Conv2d layer. In pytorch0.4.1, the output of nn.Conv2d and the output of formula are always same. But Sometimes they are different in pytorch1.1. I'm confused!!!!

````
import torch.nn as nn
torch.set_printoptions(precision=64)
input_t = torch.randn((3,3))
input_t = input_t.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).float()
class minimodel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(minimodel, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=3)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x
demo_model = minimodel()
weight = torch.load("model.ckpt")
demo_model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.ckpt"))
demo_model.eval()
output_t = demo_model(input_t)
# torch.save(demo_model.state_dict(),"model.ckpt")
print("#####output of nn.Conv2d#####")
print(output_t)
Kernel_W = weight['conv.weight']

print("####output of formula######")
print(torch.add(weight['conv.bias'],torch.sum(torch.mul(Kernel_W, input_t))))```
````

Comment: I find the diference exists whatever the version of pytorch???!!!, in addition, I tried the computation on CPU and on GPU, it exists both at all...

Comment: Have you found a way to solve this problem or have you managed to find a way to make the result the same ?